# $-1$ as quadratic residue in $p$-adic rings

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, quadratic-residues

It is well known that $-1$ is a quadratic residue in all the fields $\mathbb F_p$ for primes of $4N+1$ type. I want to know if $-1$ is always a perfect square in the rings of $p$ to the $n$-th powers, for all primes of $4N+1$ type and for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: What is "the rings of p to the n-th powers"?

Comment: I mean, for p=5, I wanted to know if -1 always has square roots in rings Z/25Z, Z/125Z, Z/625Z, and so on. I have checked it is the case up to Z/125Z (57 and 68 are the square roots of -1), but I don't know this fact applies to Z/625Z and further, thus wanted to know if there is a proof to guarantee it always holds true (probably by exploiting the law of quadratic reciprocity). @KentaS

Comment: This sounds like a job for [Hensel's lemma](https://brilliant.org/wiki/hensels-lemma/)

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't instantly get the point from the quite abstract statement of Hensel's lemma So, in short, may I understand that if -1 is a quadratic residue in Z/pZ, then -1 has square roots in all rings Z/(p^n)Z ? @Arthur

Comment: @YuanLiu no for $p=2$, but yes for $p>2$. (it is a good exercise to see why Hensel's lemma doesn't apply for $p=2$). Indeed, $-1\in\mathbb Z/4$ has no square root.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on Hensel's lemma is quite useless as an introduction. I included a better link instead. It has plenty of examples that should fit you perfectly.

Comment: Thank you so much! @Arthur

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, given that -1 has square roots in all Z/(p^n)Z for p=4N+1, may I understand that we could practically construct a p-adic number that corresponds to the imaginary unit i, by citing all the square roots of -1 in each layer? Can this be seen as a completion from Z to Z[i]? @KentaS

Comment: @YuanLiu yes, for $p\equiv1\pmod4$ there is a $p$-adic number $x\in\mathbb Z_p$ such that $x^2=-1$.